# How to listen for a mention of CurrentUser as a Discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.net

I want my bot to catch when other users mention my bot in chat.  I've tried

```
message.MentionedUsers.contains(client.CurrentUser)
```

But this returns false, I believe because MentionedUsers is a collection of SocketGuildUser, while client.CurrentUser is a SocketUser

Do I need to loop through MentionedUsers to look for the user.id? Or is there a more direct way?

Using Discord.Net 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I cant explain why your solution is not working but I have a other way for you to check if your bot is in the mentioned users using linq:

```cs
//you have to add this using if you havent yet
using System.Linq;


if(message.MentionedUsers.Any(m => m.Id == client.CurrentUser.Id))
{
   //this code will be fired if your bot was mentioned in the message
}
```